# How to change image background color in Magento 2 via XML?

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, xml

I want to change the white background color to any other color in Magento 2.

[image: Magento 2 Luma image]

How could I do it?

Comment: Please refer below link [override image.php file it is working for me](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124160/magento-2-images-background-color-do-not-apply)

Comment: not changing the , it is comming white background color alone.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the file called view.xml which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme luma you should find the view.xml under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

In this file, you would see a node inside the node.

The background color of the images is maintained here under the node.

The id attribute value of the node is referenced in the codebase.

```
<image id="product_base_image" type="image">
    <width>700</width>
    <height>560</height>
    <transparency>false</transparency>
    <background>[255, 0, 0]</background>
</image>
```

Once the values changes have been done, you will have to run

> php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

Comment: I did all those things. but not yet changed background color.

Comment: which catalog image you need to update? please share with me view.xml in your them.

Answer (score 0):

To change the image background color in Magento 2 via XML, you can add the following code to your XML layout file:

```
    <referenceBlock name="[block_name]">
        <action method="setBackgroundColor">
            <argument name="background" xsi:type="string">#000000</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Here, you should replace [block_name] with the name of the block that displays the image. The setBackgroundColor method sets the background color of the image.

The argument background sets the background color of the image. In this example, the background color is set to black (#000000).

You can adjust the color code as per your requirement.

Make sure that the block you are referencing has the setBackgroundColor method defined. If the block does not have this method, you will need to create a custom block that extends the existing block and adds this method.